# Implicit Differentiation Find dy/dx

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi this question has got me stumped. It is to find dy/dx for the equation
$$((x^2+y^2)^4+(x^4+y^4)^2)^{10}+x^5+y^5=100$$

I have done working to the following point ( if my working is correct ) :
$$10((y^4+x^4)^2+(y^2+x^2)^4)^9(2(y^4+x^4)(4y^3y'+4x^3)+4(y^2+x^2)^3(2yy'+2x))+5y^4y'+5x^4=0$$

Seriously don't know how to proceed....!

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial for formatting: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The best way to implicitly differentiate (if you only need to do so once) is writing the function as $F(x,y) = 0,$ then taking the partial derivatives $\partial F / \partial x = F_x$ and $F_y.$  Then, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-F_x}{F_y}.$